# Svelte store typescript Missing return type on function

Tags: typescript, svelte

I need to set up a very simple
store but I'm stuck with this error

> Missing return type on function

```
export interface DataState {
    error: string | null;
    loaded: boolean;
    data: GetIssuesQuery | undefined;
}
const initialState: DataState = {
    error: null,
    loaded: false,
    data: undefined
};
const store = writable<DataState>(initialState);

const dataStore = {
    subscribe: store.subscribe,
    success: (data: GetIssuesQuery) => {
        store.update((state) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                loaded: true,
                data
            };
        });
    },
    failure: (error:string) => {
        store.update(() => {
            return {
                error,
                loaded: false,
                data: undefined
            };
        });
    }
};
```

The error is triggered by:
success: (data: GetIssuesQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to your linter that enforces the hard typing of function's return value.

In your case you will need to tell what type the functions `success` and `failure` returns. Here it's easy they don't return anything, so simply use `void`:

```js
const dataStore = {
    subscribe: store.subscribe,
    success: (data: GetIssuesQuery): void => {
        // ...
    },
    failure: (error:string): void => {
        // ...
    }
};
```